# Is there a way to disable automatic movement of the pen input window?

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-surface, input-device, pen, stylus

I am using a Microsoft Surface 3 with the [newer Surface Pen](https://www.microsoft.com/surface/en-us/accessories/pen). When using the pen input window, it moves around of it's own accord. It's clearly intended to be "helpful" by moving itself where it thinks it's needed, but it more often wrong than right.

How do I get it to stop trying to be smart, and just stay where I put it?

[image: Windows 10 Pen Input]

Just to be clear, this is the window I'm talking about.